# How to do optional with an or conditions in Swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement, option-type

i am trying to do following:-

```
var isSomeThingTrue = checkSomeThing()

if (let someOptional = getSomeOptional(),
   let anotherOptional = getAnotherOptional(withSomeOptional: someOptional)) ||
   isSomeThingTrue {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Is there a way this could be achieved with **if statement** or i have to use a **guard statement** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are many ways to skin this cat so here is one more, if you move the code to be executed inside the `if` into a function to avoid code duplication the below way is in my opinion easy to read

```
if let someOptional = getSomeOptional(), let anotherOptional = getAnotherOptional(withSomeOptional: someOptional) {
    doSomething(anotherOptional)
} else if checkSomeThing() {
    doSomething(nil)
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Comment: Awesome, lol way simpler and easy to read. Thank you @Joakim Danielson .

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the `if let x = y` syntax is that the if block is only run if `y` is not nil, so you can bind it to a non-optional let-constant `x`, and `x` can be used inside the if block.

However, in your case, the if block can still be run even if `getSomeOptional()` returns nil, but `isSomeThingTrue` is true. So in the if block, you don't know if `getSomeOpional` returned nil or not. `someOptional` still has to be of an optional type. The same goes for `anotherOptional`.

Therefore, you don't need `if let` to do this, just do:

```
// unlike with the 'if let', these let constants are visible are in scope outside the if statement too
// if you don't like that for some reason, wrap the whole thing with a do { ... } block
let someOptional = getSomeOptional()
let anotherOptional = getAnotherOptional(withSomeOptional: someOptional)
if (someOptional != nil && anotherOptional != nil) || isSomeThingTrue {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

If `getAnotherOptional` takes a non-optional, use `flatMap`:

```
let anotherOptional = someOptional.flatMap(getAnotherOptional(withSomeOptional:))
```

Comment: the solution in first part doesnt use optional unwrapping, but thats exactly what i am trying to do. My point is if 'AND' condition can be with comma (,) during optional unwrapping, why not an 'OR' ( || ) condition ?  Didnt knew Flatmap could be used for optional chaining will try. Thanks.

Comment: @AshishP "why not an 'OR' condition?" You cannot unwrap an optional there, because the optional can still be nil, as I have explained.